# Spring Security OAuth2 - stored authentication object

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently using a fairly vanilla setup of Spring Security Oauth2 version 2.0.7.RELEASE with a `JdbcTokenStore` and have recently encountered an interesting issue.

I understand that as an access token is created and stored, the `Authentication` object is serialized and also persisted to the database. I understand that this is necessary and used when an access token is later used in a request. The issue is that my `Authentication` object (a custom impl of Spring Security's UserDetails interface) has is associated to other objects in my application's domain. (sample object graph might look like Authentication -> com.myapp.User -> com.myapp.PhoneNumber)

I've had to make some changes to the implementation said objects and noticed that `Authentication` objects serialized and stored to the database prior to my change no longer deserialize, which make sense because my object model has changed.

What is a recommended way for managing this scenario? Is there a way to get the `Authentication` object to serialize to JSON and not binary? I am leaning towards removing my custom information from my `Authentication` object but am wondering if there is a better approach?

Comment: Please provide the code snippets.

Comment: Arg nevermind, this question can be invalidated. After thinking about it more I realized you can simply just blow away the contents of the OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN table once your model changes. D'oh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the loop - the approach I ended up using was to extend `JdbcTokenStore` and to override the methods `serializeAuthentication` and `deserializeAuthentication` to perform serialization / deserialization using Jackson. Then in my object model, I `@JsonIgnore`'d the entities that are not really needed in authenticating a user.